# ItemUpdating event is not being triggered

Tags: remote-event-receiver

In my `AppInstalledEvent` I created 2 RERS, one for `ItemAdded` and another one for `ItemUpdating`.
The first one is being called when I hit the breakpoint, however the second one the breakpoints are never hit.

If I check SharePoint Manager, both RERs are there. (with same URL)
http://screencast.com/t/puilR4uJ

The code I use is:

```
const string RECEIVER_NAMEADDED = "PP_SC_ITEMADDED";
        const string RECEIVER_NAMEUPDATING = "PP_SC_ITEMUPDATING";

        public SPRemoteEventResult ProcessEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {

            SPRemoteEventResult result = new SPRemoteEventResult();

            switch (properties.EventType)
            {
                case SPRemoteEventType.AppInstalled:
                    this.HandleAppInstall(properties);
                    result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;
                    break;
                case SPRemoteEventType.AppUninstalling:
                    this.HandleAppUnInstall(properties);
                    result.Status = SPRemoteEventServiceStatus.Continue;
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }


        public void ProcessOneWayEvent(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            switch (properties.EventType)
            {
                case SPRemoteEventType.ItemAdded:
                    HandleItemAdded(properties);
                    break;
                case SPRemoteEventType.ItemUpdating:
                    HandleItemUpdating(properties);
                    break;
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// When the app is installed we need to associate the RER that will create the subsites when a new project List Item is created.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="properties"></param>
        private void HandleAppInstall(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            using (ClientContext clientContext =TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
            {
                //this.CleanUp(clientContext);
                this.AssociateItemAddedRemoteEventReceiverToProjectList(clientContext);
                this.AssociateItemAUpdatingRemoteEventReceiverToProjectList(clientContext);
                this.ConfigureProjectFields(clientContext);
            }
        }

 private void AssociateItemAUpdatingRemoteEventReceiverToProjectList(ClientContext clientcontext)
        {
            List projectList = clientcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Projects");
            clientcontext.Load(projectList);

            var eventReceivers = projectList.EventReceivers;
            clientcontext.Load(eventReceivers);

            clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();

            var rerExists = false;

            foreach (var rer in projectList.EventReceivers)
            {
                if (rer.ReceiverName == RECEIVER_NAMEUPDATING)
                {
                    rerExists = true;
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Found existing ItemUpdated receiver at " + rer.ReceiverUrl);
                }
            }

            if (!rerExists)
            {
                EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation receiver = new EventReceiverDefinitionCreationInformation();
                receiver.EventType = EventReceiverType.ItemUpdating;
                receiver.Synchronization = EventReceiverSynchronization.Synchronous;
                //Get WCF URL where this message was handled
                OperationContext op = OperationContext.Current;
                Message msg = op.RequestContext.RequestMessage;

                receiver.ReceiverUrl = msg.Headers.To.ToString();
                receiver.ReceiverName = RECEIVER_NAMEUPDATING;
                //Add the new event receiver to a list in the host web

                projectList.EventReceivers.Add(receiver);

                clientcontext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick is to use the ProcessEvent method instead of ProcessOneWayEvent because the RER added was synchronous!